# Add bands or new raster column in Postgis?

Tags: postgis-2.0, postgis-raster

Would it be faster to work with a new band or a new raster column for a raster dataset in Postgres with new pixel values, assuming that the size, extent and everything else relevant remains constant?
For example: If I've reclassified the raster column and want to retain the original values - should it go into a new band or just another 'reclass_rast'column?
Concerned with querying capabilities and size on disk.